# Windows Phone 8.1 application using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows phone 8.1 development.Can anyone suggest me some complete example with step by step using WCF Service. I have seen some examples but i am not able to follow and finish that examples. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question is Off Topic for SO. Please return when you have a **specific question** where we can provide a **detailed and accurate answer** and we can help you then. Cheers! :)

Comment: Try this course to get a feeling for Windows Phone. It's fairly easy and you will be able to follow WCF tutorials easily afterwards. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can call a WCF service from Windows Phone 8.1 application is if your WCF service is RESTful so you can call it with an HTTP request.

Here is a basic function that calls a WCF service and gets a string back:

```
private async void CallService()
{
   // Create HttpClient
   HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

   // Do the request (replace localhost:18362/xxx.svc/xxx by your own service url
   HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:18362/Service1.svc/GetData");

   // Get the response
   HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

   // Read the response (here a string)
   string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```